# How to show multiple timestamps at each frame using gganimate and transition_reveal?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, gganimate

I would like to create an animation for time series data. Instead of showing 1 data point at each frame, I want to show multiple data points along with time axis. For example, animation starts at time-1, I want to show values from 1 to 5 (instead of 1 only); at time-2, I want to show values from 2 to 6 (instead of 2 only), and so on. Is this achievable with transition_reveal or do I need a different function?

Example data df.ex:

```
df.ex <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1634680800, 1634681100, 1634681400, 1634681700, 1634682000, 1634682300, 1634682600, 1634682900, 1634683200,1634683500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Singapore"), 
                         value = c(11.4266394724623, 14.1984376956665, 11.2322131055487, 9.44764093205051, 3.46903702090985, 10.6564620620125, 24.2428795188011, 4.67917670299971, 1.83736168860116, 15.3431043977062)), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and example code:

```
ggplot(df.ex, mapping = aes(x = Time, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  geom_point() +
  transition_reveal(Time)
```

The output of this code is:

[image: example gif output]

Here, I want to "travel" in time and show multiple upcoming values before the animation reaches at that time stamp.

Comment: hey, not sure what you mean by point that appears before time stamp t, do you have an example figure of how that should look like?